# Div displays half of itself twice - using swipe.js

Tags: javascript, html, slider, slide.js

Trying to find a slider library that I don't need jQuery to operate. I have two images of different widths inside the same swipejs container as per the demo,

```
<div id='mSwipe' style='background-color:#ffb6c1;width:300px;height:250px;position:relative; left:800px;' class='swipe'>
  <div id="swipewrape" class='swipe-wrap'>
    <div id="slideone" style="text-align:right;"><img src="http://www.totallygaming.com/sites/default/files/rotor/Commercial%20Intelligence.JPG"/></div>
    <div id="slidetwo" style="text-align:right;"><img src="http://in-formatio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ihop-free-pancake-day-20091-600x250.jpg"/></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
  <button onclick='state_change();mySwipe.prev()'>prev</button>
  <button onclick='state_change();mySwipe.next()'>next</button>
</div>

<script>
var state = 0;
function state_change() //Dumb state change function
{
   if(state)
   {
      state = 0;
      document.getElementById('mSwipe').style.width = "300px";
   }
   else
   {
     state = 1;
     document.getElementById('mSwipe').style.width = "600px";

   }
}
```

I put in a simple little two-state state machine to see what I can do if I change the div-width before the slide effect kicks in. I put the size change in the callback methods include in swipejs at first to no avail. **I just want to change the div size each time I push the button so the image coming in fits in it**

On button presses, the div will resize to the right size, but it seems like for the big image (which is a stack of delcious pancakes), **it'll slide over and display the half of the large image twice in the swipe div**. I can change back to the smaller image just fine

**If I open my chrome console, the full image shows, and I have no further problems**.

What's up with that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cone,

I have changed your code a little bit and created a fiddle for you below.
Also giving you the jQuery commands on the Javascript commented out in case you change your mind about jQuery later on.

JavaScript

```
// pure JS
var elem = document.getElementById('slider');
window.mySwipe1 = Swipe(elem, {
    // startSlide: 4,
    // auto: 3000,
    continuous: true,
    // disableScroll: true,
    // stopPropagation: true,
    // callback: function(index, element) {},
    // transitionEnd: function(index, element) {}
});
// with jQuery
// window.mySwipe = $('#mySwipe').Swipe().data('Swipe');
```

HTML

```
<div id='slider' class='swipe'>
    <div class='swipe-wrap'>
        <div>
            <img src="http://www.totallygaming.com/sites/default/files/rotor/Commercial%20Intelligence.JPG" />
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="http://in-formatio.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/02/ihop-free-pancake-day-20091-600x250.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div style='text-align:center;padding-top:20px;'>
    <button class='prev' onclick='mySwipe1.prev()'>prev</button>
    <button class='next' onclick='mySwipe1.next()'>next</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.swipe {
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position: relative;
}
.swipe-wrap > div > img {
    margin:10%;
    width:90%;
}
#slider {
    height: auto;
    width:50%;
    left:200px;
}
```

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/yFJaf/1/)**

EDIT: Updated the fiddle, added the original image size

**[EXAMPLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Xandour/yFJaf/2/)**

Comment: You're awesome, and should feel awesome.

But I need the larger image to be at full size :(

Comment: Why have the examples been deleted?